# Changing LOG levels of Log4j2 in spring boot application on wildfly 10 logging profiles

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

We are creating an spring-boot application and using `Log4j2` for logging.

Using `log4j.xml` for logging configs. After deploying the WAR on `wildfly` from admin console, its working fine.

Now we would like to change the log levels from admin console or in anyway without changing the `log4j.xml` or without redeploying the WAR.

I referred many articles but no use.

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42026097/3301492).

Comment: We are using wildfly/jboss eap as server. SO we would like to do the log level changes from admin console or log profiles. Please explain about log profiles if this task is achievable through log profiles.

Comment: Sorry, re-read the question and realised that you need to change it via the console of WildFly.

Comment: Unfortunately WildFly does not currently support log4j2 however it's being worked on. You can track the issue here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-482

Comment: Only wildfly or even jboss 7 aslo does not support log4j2? My exact requirement is we are creating an spring boot app with maven and dev server is wildfly 10 and prod sever is jboss 7. We are using log4j2 for logging. We want to have the separate log files for separate .war files and we should be able to change the log levels dynamically during the run-time without server restart.