# Spring Boot – Configure Log Level in run time using actuator endpoint for multiple instance of microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, microservices, spring-logback

I need to enable dynamic log level changes for my spring microservices using actuator endpoint for multiple instance of microservices .

Comment: What are current properties you have set in `application.properties` ? Do you have `logback.xml` ?

Comment: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,prometheus,metrics,loggers

Comment: management.endpoints.loggers.sensitive=false

Comment: yes i have logback.xml also

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166572/change-logging-level-at-runtime-in-spring-boot-application/53166801#53166801 ?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh this approach is for single micro-service instance but i have multiple  instance of a micro service running and i want to enable the changes in all the instances